# cordova-plugin-fcm - ios upload to app store - Invalid Bundle - Info,plist unreadable - FirebaseCore.framework' does not contain a bundle executable

Tags: ios, upload, app-store, app-store-connect, cordova-plugin-fcm

I create an archive in Xcode, validation and upload to the app store is successful.

But then I get an email with error messages below.
Can I fix this without having the firebase library updated?
If so, how?

I am on Xcode 8.3.3 and it is an ionic 1 app, the app is running fine without errors on Android and Ios.

In use, latest version of cordova-plugin-fcm.

I have an issue ticket open there as well... but no answers so far.
It would be great if anybody could point me in to the right direction.

> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   /Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/FirebaseAnalytics.framework
>   is missing or could not be read.
>
> Invalid Bundle - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/FirebaseAnalytics.framework'
>   does not contain a bundle executable.
>
> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   /Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/FirebaseCore.framework
>   is missing or could not be read.
>
> Invalid Bundle - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/FirebaseCore.framework'
>   does not contain a bundle executable.
>
> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   /Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/FirebaseInstanceID.framework
>   is missing or could not be read.
>
> Invalid Bundle - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/FirebaseInstanceID.framework'
>   does not contain a bundle executable.
>
> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   /Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/FirebaseMessaging.framework
>   is missing or could not be read.
>
> Invalid Bundle - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/FirebaseMessaging.framework'
>   does not contain a bundle executable.
>
> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   /Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/GoogleIPhoneUtilities.framework
>   is missing or could not be read.
>
> Invalid Bundle - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/GoogleIPhoneUtilities.framework'
>   does not contain a bundle executable.
>
> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   /Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework
>   is missing or could not be read.
>
> Invalid Bundle - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework'
>   does not contain a bundle executable.
>
> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   /Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
>   is missing or could not be read.
>
> Invalid Bundle - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework'
>   does not contain a bundle executable.
>
> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   /Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/GoogleUtilities.framework
>   is missing or could not be read.
>
> Invalid Bundle - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/WhatEverAppName.app/www/lib/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/ios/firebase/GoogleUtilities.framework'
>   does not contain a bundle executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue.
The solution was to upgrade the Firebase library in the cordova-plugin-fcm plugin. https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

After that, delete the content from /var/folders, not the directory itself.
And delete xcodes derived data.